# Стилистика в официальном документе

Tags: стилистика

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста!
На работе всегда в приказах писали один из абзацев в следующем виде:
"Ответственным лицом **за ходом** исполнения государственного контракта и проведени**ем** экспертизы..."
Теперь руководство предлагает такую:
""Ответственным **за ход** исполнения государственного контракта и проведени**е** экспертизы...""
Скажите, как всё-таки грамотно написать, и по возможности дайте ссылку или какие-нибудь правила по данному вопросу!
Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Вера и Слава, огромное спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 4):

> "Ответственным **за ход** исполнения государственного контракта и
>   **проведение** экспертизы..."

Такая формулировка верна. *Ответственный **за что**: за ход, за проведение...*

Из словаря сочетаемости слов русского языка под ред. Денисова и Морковкина:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Правильно:

"Ответственным **за ход** исполнения государственного контракта и проведение экспертизы..."

Проверен по "Словарю грамматической сочетаемости", РАН, 2013.

Там приводится пример: Ответственность (за что?) - за выполнение приказа. Винительный падеж приводится  качестве единственного варианта.

Сравнить: наблюдать **за ходом** исполнения, отвечать **за ход** исполнения

Comment: Вера, вы стилистику проверяете по словарю сочетаемости? Или грамматику? Можно точную цитату для сочетания именно "**ответственный за ход**"? Или чего-то подобное? Не "за выполнение"?

Comment: Я имела  виду, что винительный падеж ПРОВЕРЕН  по словарю, примера "ответственный за ход" там нет. Есть еще "ответственный за порядок".

Comment: Про винительный все согласились, тут и спора нет. Но у него даже метка - стилистика. И вопиющая несуразица "ответственный за ход". Неужели слух не режет?

Comment: Ну да, режет с непривычки, но мне кажется, что мы просто привыкли к другому канцеляризму -  "ответственность за ходом",  а здесь-то падеж точно неправильный. Вообще же говоря, мне кажется, что проблема  заключается в том, что сущ. исполнение соотносится с видовой парой выполнить/выполнять, поэтому неясно, о чем идет речь: о результате или о процессе. Вот и противопоставляется исполнение (результат) и ход исполнения (процесс).

Answer (score 0):

Если вас **грамматика** интересует, то да. "За ход". Ответственный - "за что", никак не "за чем".

А вот если, как вы вопрос пометили, **стилистика**, то простите, тут варианты - "оба хуже". Не нужно тут вообще никакого "хода", это типичный канцеляризм.

**"Ответственность за исполнение возложить на [Разэтакова Такоя Сякоевича]"** - вполне достаточно.

Comment: Ответственный за ход исполнения  контролирует поэтапный процесс (ход) исполнения (обычно длительный), а ответственный за исполнение  отвечает только  за результат исполнения.

Comment: Вы откуда эту тарабарщину взяли? Сами придумали или из приказа по редакционным войскам?

Comment: Это Вы мне? Ну да, сама,  люблю что-нибудь придумывать. В конце концов, есть же понятие "Ход процесса" или это тоже "типичный канцеляризм"? Вот например: "Ход процесса кристаллизации одной соли, насыщающей раствор, очевиден - при удалении воды из раствора эта соль выделяется в осадок". Кстати, о ТАРАБАРЩИНЕ . Разг. Нечто непонятное и бессмысленное (обычно о речи).  В  общем, типично оценочная лексика (негативная!).